# Object to object mapping verification - is this extension method useful?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, extension-methods

In our .NET tests we use `NSubstitute` & `ExpectedObjects`.

Testing object expectations involves hand crafting large anonymous objects and when new properties are added we need to go back to these anonymous objects & update them.

Attempting below to get a fluent Object to DTO builder - which fails when a property is missed.

Here is the implementation:

```
        //CustomerCreatedEvent has all below properties 
        var exp1 = @event.ToDto<CustomerCreatedEvent,CustomerDetail>(
            x=> x.AggregateId.As("CustomerId"), 
            x => x.Email, // comment this out and test FAILS -> CustomerDetail.Email required
            x => x.FirstName, 
            x => x.Surname);

        var exp2 = new {
                CustomerId= @event.AggregateId,
                @event.Email,      // comment this out and test still passes
                @event.FirstName,
                @event.Surname};


        exp1.ToExpectedObject().ShouldMatch(actual);
        exp2.ToExpectedObject().ShouldMatch(actual);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is my code just adding 'noise'?
2. Is the implementation code below sound?

   public static TResult ToDto(this TSource obj, params Expression>[] items) where TSource : class
       {
           var eo = new ExpandoObject();
           var props = eo as IDictionary;

   ```
       foreach (var item in items)
       {
           var member = item.Body as MemberExpression;
           var unary = item.Body as UnaryExpression;
           var body = member ?? (unary != null ? unary.Operand as MemberExpression : null);

           if (member != null && body.Member is PropertyInfo)
           {
               var property = body.Member as PropertyInfo;
               props[property.Name] = obj.GetType()
                   .GetProperty(property.Name)
                   .GetValue(obj, null);
           }
           else
           {
               var property = unary.Operand as MemberExpression;
               if (property != null)
               {
                   props[property.Member.Name] = obj.GetType()
                       .GetProperty(property.Member.Name)
                       .GetValue(obj, null);
               }
               else
               {
                   var compiled = item.Compile();
                   var output = (KeyValuePair<string, object>)compiled.Invoke(obj);
                   props[output.Key] = obj.GetType()
                   .GetProperty(output.Value.ToString())
                   .GetValue(obj, null);
               }
           }
       }

       TResult result = Activator.CreateInstance<TResult>();
       foreach (var item in props)
       {
           result.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(result, item.Value, null);
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I would vastly prefer the variable name 'item' in your foreach loop than 'thing'

Comment: ah yep will change - had it on my mind at the time but normally wouldnt use it

Comment: Found fluent assertions which seems to have a solution for the problem - https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison

Answer (score 6):

Minor nitpick first:

> ```
> public static T2 ToDto<T1,T2>(this T1 obj, params Expression<Func<T1, dynamic>>[] items) where T1 : class
> {
> ```

I think putting generic type constraints on a new line makes them easier to spot and adds to readability (especially with long signatures) - consider:

```
public static T2 ToDto<T1,T2>(this T1 obj, params Expression<Func<T1, dynamic>>[] items)
    where T1 : class
{
```

I really don't like `T1` and `T2` for generic type parameter names. `T` is *ok* when it's the only parameter, but I'd much, much rather like to see `TSource` and `TResult` - it makes it much clearer which one serves which purpose, at a glance.

This also instantly makes it easy to find `source` a much more meaningful name than `obj`. I'm all for readable identifiers, so I would like to see `props` renamed to `properties`, and `eo` to `expandoObject`, or perhaps just `value` - I will be using these identifiers for the remainder of this post.

I like that you're using `var` - I don't understand why you're not using it here, since `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` returns a `String`:

> ```
> string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);  // need json.net
> ```

That said, the comment isn't necessary. If you referenced Json.net from a NuGet package, the IDE will tell you when/if a package is missing. If you referenced Json.net from an assembly, the project will fail to build and under "references", `Newtonsoft.Json` will appear problematic - the comment really doesn't help with anything, it's just noise.

---

In this block:

> ```
> if (member != null && body.Member is PropertyInfo)
> {
>     var property = body.Member as PropertyInfo;
>     if (property != null)
>         properties[property.Name] = source.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(source, null);
> }
> ```

The condition `if (property != null)` will always be true, because `body.Member is PropertyInfo` is necessarily true in that branch. Hence it can be simplified to this:

```
if (member != null && body.Member is PropertyInfo)
{
    var property = body.Member as PropertyInfo;
    properties[property.Name] = source.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(source, null);
}
```

The `else` branch has a redundant cast - you defined `unary` as `item.Body as UnaryExpression`; hence, `unary` already has the reference you're getting in this superfluous declaration:

> ```
> var ubody = (UnaryExpression)item.Body;
> ```

Just use `unary`, you don't need `ubody` at all.

I haven't tested it, but the type parameter in `DeserializeAnonymousType<object>` seems superfluous as well - `Activator.CreateInstance<TResult>()` will create a `TResult` object.. that you can readily return - so instead of this:

> ```
> var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
> var anon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<object>(json, Activator.CreateInstance<TResult>());
> return ((JObject)anon).ToObject<TResult>();
> ```

You'd have that:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, Activator.CreateInstance<TResult>());
```

Notice I'm letting the compiler infer the generic type parameter here.

---

Lastly, the way chained reflection methods are laid out isn't consistent between the `if` and the `else` branch - one has it like this:

> ```
> properties[property.Name] = source.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(source, null);
> ```

The other has it like that:

> ```
> properties[property.Member.Name] = source.GetType()
>     .GetProperty(property.Member.Name)
>     .GetValue(source, null);
> ```

I like how putting each instruction on a new line makes it easier to see what's going on. Some may argue that it's even easier when the dots line up:

```
properties[property.Member.Name] = source.GetType()
                                         .GetProperty(property.Member.Name)
                                         .GetValue(source, null);
```